# Are covariance and correlation this kind of joint relationships? Is this set of scatterplots a visualization of covariance or correlation?

Tags: correlation, covariance, scatterplot

This code

```
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> g = sns.pairplot(iris)
```

gives this figure

[image]

The [seaborn doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) gives this explanation about the figure above.

> Draw scatterplots for **joint relationships** and histograms for univariate distributions.

I understand covariance or correlation describes some kind of relationships between multiple random variables.

I cannot understand what is **joint** relationships.

Are "joint relationships" and "relationships" the same, in the context of probability distribution?

Is "joint relationship" a canonical statistics term?

Are covariance and correlation this kind of joint relationships?

Is this set of scatterplots a visualization of covariance or correlation?

I [googled](https://books.google.com/books?id=_f4KrEcNAfEC&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=%22joint%20relationship%22%20distribution&source=bl&ots=ZyvXXhn8Ve&sig=ACfU3U3TukgZFCHODkQC7XMSJGy2Hrk8YQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiysN3_nv3kAhWaHHAKHc28ACcQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22joint%20relationship%22%20distribution&f=false) "joint relationship" and find nothing explains whether "joint relationships" and "relationships" are the same.

Comment: Replace "joint" with "paired". There is no deeper meaning.

Comment: Generally "joint" means "among two or more."  Through its use of *univariate* and *bivariate* plots, this scatterplot matrix gives *some,* but not all, information about the joint relationship of four variables: it sheds little light on the three-variate or four-variate relationship.

Comment: @user2974951 Thanks for your comment. Does "paired" mean "pairwise"

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. Are "joint relationships" and "relationships" the same, in the context of probability distribution?

Comment: @whnlp You can say pairwise - relationship between two variables.

Comment: @user2974951 I disagree, as explained in my previous comment: "joint" is not synonymous with "pairwise."  whnlp: yes; "joint" adds no information to "relationships" in the context of a multivariate probability distribution.   For a good set of examples of this usage see, *inter alia,* https://www.york.ac.uk/media/economics/documents/herc/wp/06_05.pdf ("Alternative methods for estimating systems of
(health) equations," Casey Quinn, July 2006).

Comment: @whuber No of course "joint"!="pairwise", but in this case it is, since it is a pairs plot. Although it's not pairwise either since we are not comparing pair by pair observations.

Comment: @user2974951 I think you might be reading more into the post than intended.  My interpretation is along the lines of "a scatterplot matrix reveals *aspects* of joint relationships."  The cells of a scatterplot matrix *are* comparing paired observations, btw.  It may also be germane to note that variants of scatterplot matrices, such as varying the point symbols' graphical properties (color, shape, etc) according to other variables, or scatterplot brushing, permit exploration of trivariate and higher relationships.